# Sharepoint 2010 CPU 100% every hour

Tags: performance, sharepoint

Hi all my farm take 100% CPU time every hour for some minutes, then back run correct.
Processes affected are w3wp for my 2 web application, OWSTIMER and for that perion also STSADM. 
I try to disable lot of hourly scheduled timer job but no result.
Thanls all for help.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this guideline to use DebugDiag to investigate high CPU problem. It's not easy. Very difficult task. I would recommend getting MS SUpport to look at this. They can do it within an hour and you might save a lot of time.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919791